# Updating 2 linked moongoose schemas

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a mongoose User schema and an Organisation schema. Each user belongs to one organisation and each organisation has many users but one user which is its administrator. This user is saved in the `createdBy` field in the `organisation` document. My user schema is:

```
var User = new mongoose.Schema({
  email: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    unique: true
  },
  ...
  ...
  organisation: {
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'Organisation'
  }
});
```

And an organisation schema:

```
var Organisation = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  createdBy: { 
    type: String, 
    ref: 'User'
  }
});
```

So as you can see I use the `ref` to link the two schemas.

When I want to update the user's organisation and email, Im doing this:

```
User.findById(data.userId, function(err, user) {

    user.email = data.email;
    user.organisation.name = data.organisation;

    user.save(function(err, user){

        console.log('user is ', user);

    });
});
```

However, only the email is getting updated. Do I separately need to get the `organisation` document and update that? There's no way to update in one query?

Comment: If an organization directly references one User and a User directly references one Organization, why do they need to be in separate documents?

Comment: @Tom Ill edit question

Comment: I could be wrong but I don't think your syntax is correct. try: https://jsfiddle.net/hnomvpwm/

Comment: Also look at Mongoose's pre middleware: http://mongoosejs.com/docs/middleware.html